# Resource window of Google BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am new to Google BigQuery.
I am now logged into bq console, but the resource window for tables and datasets is too small to navigate and is pinned into bottom left, and its not resizable, please help on how can i unpin the window to navigate it.

It looks like this.

[image]

Comment: gcp is so immature  ?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like what you want is something like below

[image]

There are many way to accomplish this. I will present two of them

- Customize existing/available UI to fit your own specific needs using so called [Bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet)

> Bookmarklets are saved and used as normal bookmarks. As such, they are simple "one-click" tools which add functionality to the browser.

There is a wide usage of bookmarklets - one of which is to modify the appearance of a web page within the browser - which is exactly your use case.
You can create bookmarklet that will switch visibility of elements above the data navigator as in above example

- if your needs are more sophisticated and you are looking for more perks than just hiding elements of UI - you can look into third party IDE for BigQuery

I can recommend one to check out - [Goliath](https://potens.io/products/#goliath) - the part of [Potens.io Suite for BigQuery](http://potensio.zendesk.com). You will find there everything you would expected from professional big data IDE tool.
It is free to use and is available on [GCP Marketplace](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/potens-io/potensio)
Disclosure - I am part and lead of Potens.io Team (which is also clearly stated in my SO Profile)

Comment: exactly what i am looking for .

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean you want to unpin a project that has "Pin icon" in the screenshot?

If yes, You can unpin a project to clcik "UNPIN PROJECT" right side of bigquery console.

[image]

You have to click project(e.g bigquery-public-data) first to meet "UNPIN PROJECT".

Comment: no no , I want to unpin that "Resource" window so that I can see all the tables in dataset

Comment: There is no unpin "Resource" window. That's all you see. You can just scrolled down table section below or dragged to left for expansion.